# adding element to a list of list in python pyspark

Tags: python, list, pyspark

I have a list of list with student data of structure - `[('100', 'class 1'), ('110', 'class 2'), ('1030', 'class 2'),.....]`. This structure I get from using this command:

```
student_class = student.map(lambda x:x).zip(class)
```

Now I want to add student score to each element of the above list of list so the output becomes:

`[('100', 'class 1',score1), ('110', 'class 2',score2), ('1030', 'class 2',score3),.....]`

The students score are present in a list named `score`. How do I add the scores to above `student_class` list so as to make it `student_classScore` list?

Comment: Why not also use `zip` and `map` in spark to append scores?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have a `list` of `tuple`s and `tuple`s are immutable, you will need to create a new tuple by concentrating the existing tuple with a single-element tuple (created by `(score,)`), then appending the newly created tuple to a new list.

```
l = [('100', 'class 1'), ('110', 'class 2'), ('1030', 'class 2')]
scores = [1, 2, 3]
new_list = []
for tup, score in zip(l, scores):
    new_list.append(tup + (score,))

print new_list
>> [('100', 'class 1', 1), ('110', 'class 2', 2), ('1030', 'class 2', 3)]
```

Another but somehow less pythonic way but same concept:

```
for index, tup in enumerate(l):
    l[index] = tup + (scores[index],)
print l
>> [('100', 'class 1', 1), ('110', 'class 2', 2), ('1030', 'class 2', 3)]
```

Comment: when I tried your method 1 I got `TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration`

Comment: It means you called `zip()` with an argument that isn't iterable (not a list ,dictionary or a tuple etc.). Verify your variables' types.

Comment: the score list I have is formed from using `scores = data.map(lambda x:x).collect()`

Comment: figured out the issue! my `student_class` was an RDD so I added `.collect()` to make it a list

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using spark, you can use `zip` and `map` in spark to append scores as well.

```
student_RDD = sc.parallelize(['100', '110', '1030'])
class_RDD = sc.parallelize(['class1', 'class2', 'class2'])
score_RDD = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])

student_class_RDD = student_RDD.zip(class_RDD) # There is no need to map first
student_class_RDD.zip(score_RDD).map(lambda x: x[0] + (x[1],)).collect()
```

Out:

```
[('100', 'class1', 1), ('110', 'class2', 2), ('1030', 'class2', 3)]
```

I think it is more appropriate to use the spark solution, rather than the pure python solution, especially when the data is large, which is why you use spark, right?